# Page Templates not accurately displaying

Tags: layout, template, local.xml

In my local.xml I have two columns left declared in my theme yet 3-Columns is the layout thats displayed.  Template path hints points to the 3 column template in my selected theme.  Where else can I check other than Local?  I'm assuming admin if local is the last to parse.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default translate="label" module="page">   
    <reference name="head">

        <!-- Adding Javascript -->
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery.min.js</name>
        </action>

        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/bootstrap.min.js</name>
        </action>

        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery.scripts.js</name>
        </action>

        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/html5shiv.js</name>
            <params/><if>lt IE 9</if>
        </action>

        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/respond.min.js</name>
            <params/><if>lt IE 9</if>
        </action>


        <!-- Removing the style.css from Base-->
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type><name>css/print.css</name>
        </action>
        <!-- Adding Bootstrap Css -->
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/bootstrap.min.css</stylesheet>
        </action>



        <!-- Adding our custom style.css -->
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet>
        </action>

        <block type="core/text" name="fontawesome_cdn">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
                ]]></text>
            </action>
        </block>

    </reference>
    <!-- end HEAD -->


<reference name="header">
    <block type="cms/block" name="headerSocial" as="headerSocial">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>headerSocial</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="cms/block" name="topNav" as="topNav">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>topNav</block_id></action>
    </block>
    <block type="cms/block" name="primaryNav" as="primaryNav">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>primaryNav</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>

<block type="cms/block" name="homeFeatured" as="homeFeatured">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>homeFeatured</block_id></action>
    </block>

<block type="cms/block" name="homeBanner" as="homeBanner">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>homeBanner</block_id></action>
</block>

<reference name="footer">
        <block type="cms/block" name="footerCustomerService" as="footerCustomerService">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footerCustomerService</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="footerProducts" as="footerProducts">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footerProducts</block_id>
            </action>
        </block> 
        <block type="cms/block" name="legalFooter" as="legalFooter">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>legalFooter</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>  
        <block type="cms/block" name="socialLinks" as="socialLinks">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>socialLinks</block_id>
            </action>
        </block> 
</reference>

<block type="cms/block" name="welcomeMessage" as="welcomeMessage">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>welcomeMessage</block_id>
    </action>
</block>

<reference name="top.links">
    <remove name="top.links" />
</reference>

<remove name="left.permanent.callout" /> 



</default>

<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference> 
        <remove name="product_tag_list" />
</catalog_product_view>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>




</layout>
```

Comment: What type of page is this? A Category View Page, Product View Page, CMS Page? Each of these have admin fields for "Layout", which will take precedence over what you set in local.xml (if something is selected)

Comment: I apologize.  Category Page.

Comment: Check the category, go to "Custom Design" tab, and make sure "Page Layout" is "No Layout Updates". Also, Categories have TWO different layout handles depending on if "Is Anchor" on the "Display Settings" tab is set to yes or no. "Yes", the layout handle is "catalog_category_layered", "No" the layout handle is "catalog_category_default".

Comment: Thats not changing it.  Its defaulting to 3 columns of the package Im using.  Is that set in the base page.xml?

Comment: Please update your question, to include the code you have in local.xml that you're using to attempt to change the layout.

Comment: Sorry but that update of yours is not enough, need to see the XML instructions from the start of the layout handle. I'll try to supply an answer either way one moment.

Comment: Thanks, my guess is you are simply using the wrong layout handle. Your instructions are for "Anchor" categories, you may just need to change "catalog_category_layered" to "catalog_category_default"

Answer (score 1):

If you're category is set to "Is Anchor" => "No", local.xml should have something similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><file>page/2columns-left.phtml</file></action>
        </reference>
    <catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

For Anchor categories, the layout handle is different, this will be the only difference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><file>page/2columns-left.phtml</file></action>
        </reference>
    <catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

Comment: Inserting those killed all layouts.

Comment: The entire file should not be added to your existing local.xml, just the layout handle and it's contents (i.e. "catalog_category_default"). The examples above would be if you had no local.xml file prior to this.

Comment: I only added between the handles.

Comment: I'm not really sure where in your source code it is going wrong. Do you have logging turned on and is anything showing up in var/log/system.log or var/log/exception.log? The source code you have in your question is correct already. It may just be that you need to change "catalog_category_layered" to "catalog_category_default" depending on the settings of "Is Anchor" on the category.